# azure-api-management Create Operation using Powershell

Tags: azure-api-management

I working on script to create Azure API through Powershell.
Mainly looking for to add/update API operation through Powershell script.
Can someone point to good documentation for that ?

Answer (score 0):

please check out our REST API: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dn776326.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396